# JavaFX application permanently freezing when executing loops on Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I got the following code:

```
exch.setOnAction(e -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            BrowserThread.driver.findElement(By.linkText("Premium Exchange")).click();

            String strVal = BrowserThread.driver.findElement(By.id("premium_exchange_stock_wood")).getText();
            String strVal2 = BrowserThread.driver.findElement(By.id("premium_points")).getText();

            int intVal = Integer.parseInt(strVal);
            int intVal2 = Integer.parseInt(strVal2);

            if (intVal >= 64 && intVal2 >= 1) {

                BrowserThread.driver.findElement(By.name("buy_wood")).clear();
                BrowserThread.driver.findElement(By.name("buy_wood")).sendKeys("64"); //enter 64 in the 'buy box'
                BrowserThread.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Calculate best offer ']")).click(); //click calculate best offer
                BrowserThread.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='premium_exchange']/div/div[2]/button")).click(); //click buy
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(BrowserTab.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            } else {
                LogTab.log.appendText("Not enough premium points.\n");
            }
            if (stop.isPressed()) {
                LogTab.log.appendText("Stopped task.\n");
                break;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MarketTab.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } 

    });
```

It basically refreshes a webpage infinitely when a button is pressed on the GUI.

There is a button to start the loop (exch), and a button to break the loop (stop). But my problem is, the GUI freezes when it executes tasks on the browser. This applies to everything, not just this for-loop.

For example, I have a run-button to open the selenium web browser. The GUI freezes until the web browser has loaded completely.

I checked around and found out I have to use threads, but I have no idea where to start. I tried making a separate class for the browser to run on a different thread, but that didn't work and I can't seem to find out what I did wrong.

BrowserThread class:

```
public class BrowserThread extends Thread {

static WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;
private String browsertype;

public BrowserThread(String name, String browsertype) {
    super(name);
    this.browsertype = browsertype;
}

// set up method to initialize driver object
public void setUp(String browsertype) throws Exception {

    if (browsertype.contains("Chrome")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","res\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    } else if (browsertype.contains("PhantomJS")) {
        driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
        System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "res\\phantomjs.exe");
    } else if (browsertype.contains("PhantomJS Linux")) {
        driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
        System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "res/phantomjs.exe");
    }
    baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/";
    driver.get(baseUrl);
}


}
```

Comment: Follow the [JavaFX concurrency documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm).  [Search StackOverflow for JavaFX Task and Service information](https://www.google.com/search?q=javafx+task+service+stackoverflow).

Comment: 1. Threads dont work that way. Just because a method is on a class extending Thread it will not be executed in another Thread. 2. Dont execute Stuff on the EDT; your complete event Handler runs on it hence blocking.